# Automatically enable/disable data mobile

Tags: battery, mobile-data

Mobile data have enabled all the time drastically reduces the battery, is there any way to automatically turn on mobile data for 5min and then turn off this each (~)1 hour?

Comment: An [tag:automation] app can do this fairly easily (for Android 5+, root access would be needed) but your objective is not sketched out clearly.

Comment: If you want a solution using automation (MacroDroid) I can suggest

Comment: As Firelord mentioned, you would need to add details to present *requirements fully*

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there're no native settings in Android to achieve that. But there are several "battery savers" doing exactly that, which I call [Data Stutterer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_batterysaver#group_510).

One candidate holding the top of the list for a long time was [JuiceDefender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.latedroid.juicedefender), which unfortunately got its last update in 2012. [GreenPower](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gpo.greenpower) is still updated, and offers the same functionality:

[image: JuiceDefender] [image: GreenPower]
<sup>*JuiceDefender* and *GreenPower* (source: *Google Play;* click images for larger variants)</sup>

There are other comparable apps out there. If you want a good app recommendation, please ask for that at our sister site after having read [Where to ask for app recommendations?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575) (SR has quite strict rules, so make sure your question there has all required details).